# Tensorflow. NxD matrix multiply NxD matrix to give NxDxD matrix

Tags: python, tensorflow

for example

```
   A=[[3,2],
      [1,3],
      [4,3]]

   B=[[4,1],
      [2,1],
      [2,4]]
```

For each row vector of matrix; I want to perform column-row multiplication

```
result = []

for i in range(3):
    x = tf.matmul(tf.reshape(A[i],[2,1]), tf.reshape(B[i],[1,2])) # gives 2x2 matrix
    result.append(x)

tf.stack(result)
```

I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way of completely get rid off the loop as in practical I need loop thousands of times

Answer (score 0):

Luckily, Tensorflow supports "batched" matrix multiplies, so the following should be sufficient:

```
A = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [3,2])
B = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [3,2])
AA = tf.reshape(A,[3,2,1])
BB = tf.reshape(B,[3,1,2])
print(tf.matmul(AA,BB))
>>> <tf.Tensor 'MatMul_1:0' shape=(3, 2, 2) dtype=float32>
```